# Can't uninstall/reinstall .NET Framework 3.5 with DISM

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, .net-framework

My net framework 3.5 is broken. Verification tool ([Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224223636/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx)) says it's OK, but its not.

Net framework 3.5 can't be just uninstalled/installed on Windows 7. But you can do this by add/remove windows features. For me this doesn't work, I receive thus (not very helpful) error message ...

```
"An error occurred. not all of the updates were successfully uninstalled"
```

I found DISM tool which does exactly same, but have log. And now:

```
DISM /online /disable-feature /FeatureName:NetFx3
```

1603 error. And log:

http://pastebin.com/4jBkEiT6

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: hate to say this but have you tried restarting the machine and running it again? I would also try running the tool on safemode

Comment: I need the CBS log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made IT!

After couple of hours I accidentally found solution to my problem.

Framework 3.5 somehow uses 2.0, and for 2.0 is known problem with "vanishing" config files:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\
```

There have been files `*.config.default` but no `*.config` files.
So... I used `*config.default` files to create `.config` files and everything worked.

Comment: You have no idea, how much time you just saved me.

I've had this issue twice now... and last time I reimaged my work PC in order to fix it.

GOD SEND.  Thankyou :P

Answer (score 1):

This answer was the beginning of solving my problem. I have Win7 and framework3.5. I deleted 3.5 and programs said: point the registry key to the framework folder. 3.5 standalone did quit without saying nothing.  4.5 from the windowsupdate did not help either. 3 days later and hundreds of pages readed i understood. Framework 3.5 is based on 2.0  Aha! So solve this first.

The errror file produced by the setup verification tool [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224223636/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx)  gives info of which files are missing in the micro.net folder.
I searched for the missing files in the sxs folder, because they are there, and injected them in the expected places.
The error file says also wich registry keys are missing, and also their values. Make them.
At the end the tool said that at least framework 2 was properly installed...

The net framework repair tool, does not repair anything. Forget the tick that does nothing in the embeded framework3.5 in optionalfeatures.exe apparently equal to DISM.  You have to do it manually... outch.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20230531011953/https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=30135).

According to it's blurb:

> This tool detects and tries to fix some frequently occurring issues
> with the setup of or with updates to the Microsoft .NET Framework.

Currently it supports repairing .NET Framework 4 and .NET 3.5 SP1 (includes .NET 3.0 SP2 and .NET 2.0 SP2), on Windows 7, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista and Windows XP.

You can also try [Aaron Stebner's excellent .Net clean-up utility](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301085724/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx).

> - This tool is designed as a last resort for cases where install, uninstall, repair or patch installation did not succeed for unusual reasons.  It is not a substitute for the standard uninstall procedure.
> - The cleanup tool contains logic so that if it is run on an OS version that includes the .NET Framework as an OS component, it will not offer the option to clean it up.

Comment: Forgot to say - tool does nothing. It repairs only those Frameworks which has not been with win 7 -> 3.0, 4.0 others dont show.

Comment: @andrew8666 - I know for a fact that the tool in question CAN AND WILL remove `.NET Framework 3.5` from `Windows 7`.  So your information is wrong.

Comment: @Ramhound http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/132/cleanup.png/

Comment: From Stebner's site: "Not all of the above products will appear in the UI for the .NET Framework cleanup tool on every operating system.  The cleanup tool contains logic so that if it is run on an OS version that includes the .NET Framework as an OS component, it will not offer the option to clean it up."